# Show 'more' option to show after window size is 480px

Tags: jquery, html, css

What I'm trying to do is essentially a show and hide but only when the screen size is 480px or smaller.

Its a simple menu. Show all items if the window size is not a max-size of 480px. When the window size is smaller or equal to 480px, give the option to show more of the menu. But if the user clicks the 'More' option, hide the first 2 items and replace with the hidden options. And in vice versa.

Example: (Window size 480px):

```
Home
Email
... More

<!---- 'MORE' CLICKED ----!>

People
Explore
... More
```

So my question is this: how do I replace the first div with the second and make it toogle?

My code:

```
$('a.show-more').click(function(){
    $('.mobile-1').hide();
    $('.mobile-2').show();
},function(){
    $('.mobile-1').show();
    $('.mobile-2').hide();
});
```

Here is a [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/W3Sav/7/) to show what I'm working with. Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.is(':visible')` to decide what to hide/show and then just append the `...more` to the end of the displayed element.

See [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/W3Sav/15/)

```
$(function () {
    $('.more').click(function () {
        if ($('.mobile-1').is(":visible")) {
            $('.mobile-1').hide();
            $('.mobile-2').show();
            $(this).appendTo($('.mobile-2'));
        } else {
            $('.mobile-1').show();
            $('.mobile-2').hide();
            $(this).appendTo($('.mobile-1'));
        }
    });


    $(window).resize(function () {
        if ($(window).height() > 480) {
            $('.mobile-1').show();
            $('.mobile-2').show();
            $('.more').hide();
        } else {
            $('.mobile-1').show();
            $('.mobile-2').hide();
            $('.more').show().appendTo($('.mobile-1'));
        }
    });

    // $(window).resize(); // if you do away with your css height check

});
```

Comment: This works, however when resizing back to a larger resolution ; it doesn't show all items. Any idea of a fix?

Comment: You can do away with your fancy css height check and just add `$(window).resize();` as a last line in the code.

Answer (score 1):

I think your list is not properly declared because you use some divs instead of only LI items, so you can try this structure:

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li class="item">
        <a href="/home/">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="item">
        <a href="/home/">Email</a>
    </li>
    <li class="item mobile-2">
        <a href="/home/">People</a>
    </li>
    <li class="item mobile-2">
        <a href="/home/">Explore</a>
    </li>
    <li class="more">
        <a class="show-more">... More</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

That uses only LI with no DIV tags, and so I've added a class to the items that will be toggled.

And then you can control visibility with this code:

```
    $('a.show-more').click(function(){
      $('.item').toggle();   
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a bunch of issues in your code:

1) All `<ul>` tags should have only `<li>` tags as their direct children.  You shouldn't put `<div>` tags in there.  You can add classes on the `<li>`.

2) Your click handler isn't structured correctly.  It should only take one function, not two.

3) The `<a>` tags in your nav should be set to `display:block` so that you can click anywhere on the background color, not just on the words.

here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/W3Sav/12/